# Updating Multiple Products with API

Tags: rest, post, get

I'm trying to update thousands of products on an ecommerce site (Houzz) using a POST request in Postman, but I'm not sure how to format a large quantity. I'm able to successfully update the product one at a time, but how does it work when you need to update 10,000+? How would I format a body request to update a complete list of SKUs? I've tried several different options but can't find anything that works.

This is the request and response for one single SKU.

REQUEST:

```
<UpdateInventoryRequest>
 <SKU>101-ABR</SKU>
 <Action>update</Action>
 <Quantity>0</Quantity>
 </UpdateInventoryRequest>
```

RESPONSE:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <UpdateInventoryResponse>
     <Ack>Success</Ack>
     <Version>149</Version>
     <Timestamp>2023-08-25T04:36:34.00Z</Timestamp>
     <ProductId>26123316</ProductId>
     <SKU>101-ABR</SKU>
</UpdateInventoryResponse>
```

Below is a screenshot with more information:

[image]

```
[API docs][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Py1VU.png
[API docs][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXoJn.png
[API docs][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3e6IE.png
```

Comment: if you share the api docs from the sellers portal, we can try to help you further.  Houzz doesn't have any public api docs.

Comment: Thanks, @JeremyFiel! There's no option to add a PDF so I just dropped in 3 screenshots of the relevant section from the documentation. Happy to grab more if it's helpful, but that's about all there is, not much information in their document.

Answer (score 0):

this api is terrible... but besides my humble opinion

have you tried repeating elements? Otherwise, it doesn't say much in the way of anything else.

```xml
<UpdateInventoryRequest>
 <SKU>101-ABR</SKU>
 <Action>update</Action>
 <Quantity>0</Quantity>
</UpdateInventoryRequest>
<UpdateInventoryRequest>
 <SKU>102-ABC</SKU>
 <Action>update</Action>
 <Quantity>0</Quantity>
</UpdateInventoryRequest>
<UpdateInventoryRequest>
 <SKU>103-ABD</SKU>
 <Action>update</Action>
 <Quantity>0</Quantity>
</UpdateInventoryRequest>
```

Comment: You're definitely not wrong. It's incredibly sparse. That's sincerely a great suggestion, I did try that but it didn't work. I assume there's got to be some special combination of repetition that I just haven't figured out yet. I'll keep trying different things and hopefully come across a solution. Thank you for chiming in!

Comment: There may be a parent element for bulk operations but there's no indication of it. Otherwise, if you're doing this with code, you can just loop through a list and make 10000 calls, make sure you add a small timeout to avoid rate limiting. if you're doing this manually, sucks to be you.  Haha

Comment: Good idea, I'll try to figure out writing a loop to handle it. No way I'm doing this manually haha. Thanks so much for your help!